# Variable expected in string.replace()

Tags: java

I want to remove the preceding string **"+91"** from all the phone numbers that are acquired from my code. To accomplish this task, I am using this code:

```
   for(int i=0; i<mobileArray.get(1).size(); i++){

        if(mobileArray.get(1).get(i).contains("+91")) {

            mobileArray.get(1).get(i) = mobileArray.get(1).get(i).replace("+91", "");
            mobileArray.get(1).set(i,mobileArray.get(1).get(i));
        }
    }
```

Here `mobileArray` is a 2D arraylist, where the first index is filled with a list of names and the second index is filled with their respective phone numbers. But when I execute the code, I keep getting this error

> Variable expected

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Error is your left hand side operator in if condition should be variable

Comment: `[["ABC", "DEF"], ["+91623", "+91237"]]` Something like this.

Comment: You can't do `list.get(i) = ...`. If you want to update a list entry, use **`list.set(i, ...)`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
for(int i=0; i<mobileArray.get(1).size(); i++){
   if(mobileArray.get(1).get(i).contains("+91")) {
      mobileArray.get(1).set(i, mobileArray.get(1).get(i).replace("+91", ""));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign a return type in Java (or many other languages), which is what you're trying to do with `...get(i) = ...`.

I think what you're looking for is `List.set(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```java
mobileArray.get(1).set(i, your operation)
```

Comment: Yea, tried that, but still getting the error

Comment: Comment your above line where you're setting with =

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: Remove                mobileArray.get(1).get(i) = mobileArray.get(1).get(i).replace("+91)  this

Comment: @LowCool that is incorrect.

Comment: Try your answers first, @LowCool. It's `mobileArray.set...`. not .get(1).set.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Henry's answer, you can't assign a value to the output of a method. Although the correct operation in this case would be to use `List#set`, it would end up being redundant with the line below it. What you probably want is to combine both lines like this:

```java
if (mobileArray.get(1).get(i).contains("+91")) {
    mobileArray.get(1).set(i, mobileArray.get(1).get(i).replace("+91", ""));
}
```

Because the `String#replace` method returns the changed string (and the get method is still called before the set method), you can change it directly when setting the value.